# Set Cookie time format android

Tags: android, android-webview, setcookie

I am trying to set cookie manually inside android webview but I want to know how to generate this expiry time. What is this date format? "Thursday, December 31, 2020, 11:59:59 PM"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date format is MMMM dd, yyyy, hh:mm:ss aaa  useful link [Datetime formats](https://gist.github.com/y-gagar1n/8469484)